# Trouble using Websockets with Julia

Tags: websocket, julia

I am trying to connect to an API that uses websockets.  I need to do the following:

1. Connect to the websocket using a given URI
2. Send a login request
3. Send a request for the required data stream(s)
4. Store the returned streamed data in an array for immediate processing (the array will be continually updated while data is streamed)
5. When finished collecting data, send a logout request

I have a general understanding of websockets, but have never tried to connect to a websocket.  I have read through the “documentation” for packages HTTP (which I have used before), WebSockets, and DandelionWebSockets.  Each has left me scratching my head trying to understand how to implement the above tasks.

Would someone please help by showing me, line-by-line, how to set up the above tasks and also explain why each line or function is used?  (Assume I have the correct URI, login, data, and logout request formats.)

Comment: People will be more satisfied with your question if you show some code you already wrote. Just try to modify any of the code examples in the websocket libraries and report what it does wrong.

Comment: Without code this looks like a "do my work" question that people on SO do not like too much. Note also that your points 2,3,5 totally depend on the API of the service that you are trying to connect to. If you are learning how to program perhaps you could start with a smaller question "how to send the login request" - explain the API and what Julia code you wrote to access it. Another type of question that will also work on SO is to present a correct code e.g. in Python that does the login request and ask how to do it in Julia.